# Any way to check if a css file is referenced somewhere in the solution? Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio

I am working on updating all of the CSS files and want to make sure the old files arent referenced anywhere in the solution.  I guess I could always do a Ctrl+Find of the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/front/css/style.css" />
```

but I was hoping to be able to have a quick way to see how many times and where the file is being referenced.  Similar to how you can do code inspection for various classes you call throughout the project.

**My Second goal is to remove all CSS/Js files that aren't being used from the solution altogether!**

Any help would be awesome.  Working in VS 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running the code with the old file deleted and look for all of the errors that the code throws. (All of the can't find file errors)

*Note: For all of you programmers that see this and feel like crying. I know that this is not the cleanest way of doing this but it should work and is easy to do. Let me know if there is a better way of doing this.*

Comment: I also want to remove the files from the project if they're not being used, but I don't want to do it pre-maturely.  I'll accept if there isn't a better idea :)  I like this as a simple fix so far.

Comment: well you could just change the name of the file to something like oldStyle.css

Comment: thanks @nendoTaka.  I don't have any other "better" ideas.  In reality I was hoping to find a way to see what files are referenced so I could clean up the clutter in a very large project. Cheers +1

Comment: Hey @Spets I just found this after looking into it again I don't know if it works but here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dechx2tz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the Developer Tools in Chrome to find out the local resources your page is using. Press Ctrl + Shift + I on Chrome and go to the Sources tab, then compare them to your project files and delete what you do not need.

Answer (score -1):

Run this from a cmd file in your source file directory

```
find -i-n *.*  "css">>Results.txt
```